# fetch the data for past three hours only from current time stamp from db2 tables having timestamp column is of Char datatype

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I am using below query :

```
Select 
  a."System_Name",
  a."Comp_Mem_Pct",
  b."CPU_Usage",
  SUBSTR(a."Timestamp",2,2 )||'-'||SUBSTR(a."Timestamp",4,2)||'-'||SUBSTR(a."Timestamp",6,2) AS date_ 
from 
  "ITMUSER"."Unix_Memory" a, 
  "ITMUSER"."SMP_CPU" b 
where 
  a."System_Name"=b."System_Name" 
  and a."System_Name" in ('vil_amdox9:KUX','vil_ahmpumapp08_nsd:KUX')
```

Note :
timestamp column is of Char datatype

Comment: You should use dateadd.

Comment: The above query is working fine for fetching whole data but i need to edit it to capture data for past 3 hours only from current timestamp. Can you provide me the above edited query .

Comment: Why the plsqldeveloper tag? Is Oracle involved somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what dbms you're using but this is for sql server:

```
Select a."System_Name",
a."Comp_Mem_Pct",
b."CPU_Usage",
SUBSTR(a."Timestamp",2,2 )||'-'||SUBSTR(a."Timestamp",4,2)||'-'||SUBSTR(a."Timestamp",6,2) AS date_ 
from "ITMUSER"."Unix_Memory" a, 
"ITMUSER"."SMP_CPU" b 
where 
a."System_Name"=b."System_Name" 
and a."System_Name" in ('vil_amdox9:KUX','vil_ahmpumapp08_nsd:KUX')  
and convert(smalldatetime, a."Timestamp",) > (SELECT DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Hi President, thanks for your quick response, i have to run this query in  IBM DB2 dbms .

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the WHERE clause:

```
AND TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(a."Timestamp",'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI:SS'))
 > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 3 HOUR
```